# Find the value of $21D$ when elements of matrix are in H.P.

Tags: matrices, determinant

If $det$ represents and determinant and 
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
5 & 4 & a_6 \\
a_7 & a_8 & a_9
\end{bmatrix}=D
$$

and $a_1,a_2,a_3,5,4,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9$ are in Harmonic Progression then find the value of $21D$

As common difference corresponding Arithmetic Progression will be $\frac{1}{20}$ so do we need to find each element with the help of it or there is some better method?

Comment: The best method is usually the fastest method and finding each element and then calculating the determinant looks pretty fast to me. I got $\frac{1750}{3}$ probably in less time than it took you to format and post the question.

Comment: @almagest Value of $21D$ is 50 so I think you need to check your best and fastest method.

Comment: That is because you have a typo in the question: you put 5 instead of 4 as the central element. If you change it to 4, then I agree that the answer is 50.

Comment: I started by getting the AP as $0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,\dots$, then the HP as $20,10,\frac{20}{3},5,4,\frac{10}{3},\frac{20}{7},\frac{5}{2},\frac{20}{9}$, then I calculated the determinant.

Comment: @almagest Thanx!!!