# If $a_1, \ldots ,a_9$ are in harmonic progression, then find the value of the determinant

Tags: determinant

If $a_1, \ldots ,a_9$ are in harmonic progression ,then find the value of the determinant 
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 &a_2&a_3\\ 
 5&4&a_6\\ 
 a_7&a_8&a_9\\ 
\end{vmatrix}
$$

---

I calculated the terms as $a_1=\frac{20}{1},a_2=\frac{20}{2},a_3=\frac{20}{3},a_4=\frac{20}{4},a_5=\frac{20}{5},a_6=\frac{20}{6},a_7=\frac{20}{7},a_8=\frac{20}{8},a_9=\frac{20}{9}$ but now calculating the determinant is tedious.Is there some other elegant method possible?

Comment: perform a raw or column operation

Comment: After taking out the factor $20$ in each column I fed it to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+%7B%7B1,1%2F2,1%2F3%7D,%7B1%2F4,1%2F5,1%2F6%7D,%7B1%2F7,1%2F8,1%2F9%7D%7D) and got $1/3360$.  As it is non-zero I think it is tedious.  Your determinant is then $20^3/3360$

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755160/find-the-value-of-21d-when-elements-of-matrix-are-in-h-p which did not attract an answer either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after taking $20^3$ common and performing the following row operations

replace  $R_2$ with $R_2-\frac{R1}{4}$
replace $R_3$ with $R_3-\frac{R1}{7}$
I got this 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1/2& 1/3\\ 
 0 & 3/40& 1/12\\ 
 0 & 3/56& 4/63\\ 
\end{vmatrix}

which didn't take much time now calculate the determinant about column 1

I got $det(A)=\frac{20^3}{3360}$